# Kubernetes start pods in batches for a node

Tags: kubernetes, startup

For some application，start or restart need more resources than running。for exapmle：es/flink。if a node have network jitter，all pods would restart at the same time in this node。When this happens，cpu usage becomes very high in this node。it would increase resource competition in this node。

now i want to start pods in batches for only one node。how to realize the function now？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes have auto-healing

You can let the POD crash and Kubernetes will auto re-start them soon as get the sufficient memory or resource requirement

Or else if you want to put the wait somehow so that deployment wait and gradually start one by one

you can use the sidecar and use the POD lifecycle hooks to start the main container, this process is not best but can resolve your issue.

Basic example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sidecar-starts-first
spec:
  containers:
  - name: sidecar
    image: my-sidecar
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
          - /bin/wait-until-ready.sh
  - name: application
    image: my-application
```

[image]

**OR**

You can also use the **Init container** to check the other container's health and start the main container POD once one POD is of another service.

[Init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

i would also recommend to check the Priority class : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/

Comment: my Scenes is，first stop all pod in a node，then restart pods in batch at this node。maybe i can try Priority class。thank you

Comment: Priority class only can set Priority，all pods in this node would start at same time，not in batch manually。In fact，i have a es cluster. 10+ es node in one node. the es cluster is online.we have 100+ es nodes.i cannot modify yaml.it will restart the whole cluster.

Comment: i resolve it.the plan is easy. initcontainer and sleep 600s